# C++ Assignment Assistance

Tags: c++

I have to create a nested loop code that asks the user for a score of the archers, there are 4 rounds and 3 archers, so every rounds the program should ask the user to prompt another 3 values for the archers. The problem is that it just keeps asking for archer scores, it won't go to the next round, it wouldn't even end the current round and show the average score in that round.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //DECLARATIONS
    int score;
    int round;
    int total;
    double average = 0; // average score of an archer

    for (round = 0; round < 4;) {
        cout << "Please enter the Archer's Score' ";
        cin >> score;
        if (score<0, score> 60) {
            cout << "\nThe value you entered is out of range, Please enter a number between 0 - 60 \n";
        }
        total = total + score;
    }

    cout << "Total Score = " << total << endl;
    average = total / round;
    cout << "Average Score = " << average << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (score<0, score> 60) {` does not do what you want.

Comment: total is uninitialized. Maybe you should increment round.

Comment: You never increment `round`. Consult your textbook, and **try something simpler.**

Comment: I wish there there was an annual "worst title" competition on Stackoverflow :| This isn't it but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?  The variable round in  "for loop" never increases.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //DECLARATIONS
    int score;
    int round;
    int total;
    int count;
    double average = 0; // average score of an archer

    for (round = 0; round < 4; round++) {
        total = 0;
        for(count = 0; count < 3;)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the Archer's Score' ";
            cin >> score;
            if (score<0 || score> 60) {
                cout << "\nThe value you entered is out of range, Please enter a number between 0 - 60 \n";
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                total = total + score;
            }
        }

        cout << "Total Score = " << total << endl;
        average = total / count;
        cout << "Average Score = " << average << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `round` and the `for` condition. You have correctly initialized the round variable, and set the correct condition for the loop to exit, but your issue lies in meeting that condition, how can you make the round variable meet the exit condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (round = 0; round < 4;)
```

This for loop is infinite because the round variable is never incremented.

```
if (score < 0 || score > 60)
```

Here you are producing an error message but not allowing the user to enter another score to replace the incorrect score.